# Keeping state in sync between server and GUI in realtime

Tags: user-interface, synchronization, distributed-caching

I am looking for a library that will help me keep some state in sync between my server and my GUI in "real time". I have the messaging and middleware sorted (push updates etc), but what I need is a protocol on top of that which guarantees that the data stays in sync within some reasonably finite period - an error / dropped message / exception might cause the data to go out of syn for a few seconds, but it should resync or at least know it is out of sync within a few seconds.

This seems like it should be something that has been solved before but I can't seem to find anything suitable - any help much appreciated

More detail - I have a Rich Client (Silverlight but likely to move to Javascript/C# or Java soon) GUI that is served by a JMS type middleware.
I am looking to re engineer some of the data interactions to something like as follows

Each user has their own view on several reasonably small data sets for items such as:

- Entitlements (what GUI elements to display)
- GUI data (e.g. to fill drop down menus etc)
- Grids of business data (e.g. a grid of orders)
- Preferences (e.g. how the GUI is laid out)

All of these data sets can be changed on the server at any time and the data should update on the client as soon as possible.
Data is changed via the server – the client asks for a change (e.g. cancel a request) and the server validates it against entitlements and business rules and updates its internal data set which would then send the change back to the GUI. In order to provide user feedback an interim state may be set on the gui (cancel submitted or similar) which is the over ridden by the server response.

At the moment the workflow is:

- User authenticates
- GUI downloads the initial data sets from the server (which either loads them from the database or some other business objects it has cached)
- GUI renders
- GUI downloads a snapshot of the business data
- GUI subscribes to updates to the business data
- As updates come in the GUI updates the model and view on screen

I am looking for a generalised library that would improve on this

- Should be cross language using an efficient payload format (e.g. Java back end, C# front end, protobuf data format)
- Should be transport agnostic (we use a JMS style middleware we don’t want to replace right now)
- The client should be sent a update when a change occurs to the server side dataset
- The client and server should be able to check for changes to ensure they are up to date
- The data sent should be minimal (minimum delta)
- Client and Server should cope with being more than one revision out of sync
- The client should be able to cache to disk in between session and then just get deltas on login.

I think the ideal solution would be used something like

- Any object (or object tree) can be registered with the library code (this should work with data/objects loaded via Hibernate)
- When the object changes the library notifys a listener / callback with the change delta
- The listener sends that delta to the client using my JMS
- The client gets the update and can give that back to the client side version of the library which will update the client side version of the object
- The client should get sufficient information from the update to be able to decide what UI action needs to be taken (notify user, update grid etc)
- The client and server periodically check that they are on the same version of the object (e.g. server sends the version number to the client) and can remediate if necessary by either the server sending deltas or a complete refresh if necessary.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot!

I have a project going on which deals with the Synchronization aspect of this in Javascipt on the front end. There is a testing server wrote in Node.JS (it actually was easy once the client was was settled).

Basically data is stored by key in a dataset and every individual key is versioned. The Server has all versions of all data and the Client can be fed changes from the server. Version conflicts for when something is modified on both client and server are handled by a conflict resolution callback.

It is not complete, infact it only has in-memory stores at the moment but that will change over the new week or so.

The actual notification/downloading and uploading is out of scope for the library but you could just use Sockets.IO for this.

It currently works with jQuery, Dojo and NodeJS, really it's got hardly any dependencies at all.

The project (with a demo) is located at https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt